# vector subscription out of range c++

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that reads integers from file, stores it in vector and use count sort to sort the integers and write them in new file. My problem ocurs when i run Countsort function, the breakpoint happens at this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < C.size(); i++) {
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
}
```

my code looks like this:

```
    //COUNT SORT
void countsort() {

    int max = A[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) {
        if (A[i] > max) { 
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    //cout << "NAJVECJE STEVILO JE: " << max << endl; SAMO ZA TEST
    vector<int> C(max + 1);
    vector<int> B(A.size()); 

    for (int i = 0; i < C.size(); i++) {
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < C.size(); i++) {
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = C.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        B[C[A[i]] - 1] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        A[i] = B[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course there are lots of things that can go wrong in `B[C[A[i]] - 1]`, but it's hard to tell exactly what from the code snippet. When you hit the breakpoint in the debugger(?), you should check the values and see which one is wrong.

Comment: There are really weird values in vector C and i have no idea why, the problem is vector C contains as much indexes as it is the max value of vector A. For example in vector A the max value is 400, for some reason vector C contains 400 integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you write something to `B` vector you should probably initialize it firt like you did with `C`.

```
B = vector<int>(A.size());
```

Also I don't see any point of printing `B[i]` as it may not be assigned any value when you print it.

**Edit #1**

Your loop is not correct. Take a look at this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < C.size(); i++) {
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
}
```

**Edit #2**

Try this code.

```
vector<int> A, B;
//COUNT SORT
void countsort() {
    int max = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) {
        if (A[i] > max) {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    vector<int> C(max + 1);
    B = vector<int>(A.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < C.size(); i++) C[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < C.size(); i++) C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];

    for (int i = A.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        B[C[A[i]] - 1] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++) cout << B[i];
}

int main(void) {
    A.push_back(1);
    A.push_back(2);
    A.push_back(3);
    A.push_back(4);
    A.push_back(2);
    A.push_back(2);
    A.push_back(1);
    countsort();
}
```

Comment: I did this, but i still am getting that same error and i have no idea what triggers it. The numbers are all counted correctly in C array as i can see on the brake point.

Comment: @anthraxa, check out my edit. I found another problem in loop for calculating `C[i]`.

Comment: this is the thing is logical, but then the error pops on the next for loop

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

First you zero whole `C` vector

```
for (int i = 0; i < C.size(); i++)
{ 
    C[i] = 0;
}
```

In second loop you may not change `C[0]` so it will remain `0`

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
}
```

In third loop in my analysis you never change `C[0]`

```
for (int i = C.size() - 1; i > 0; i-- )
{
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
}
```

In last loop

```
for (int i = A.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    B[C[A[i]] - 1] = A[i];
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    cout << B[i] << " ";
}
```

**`A[i]`** may equal `0`, so `C[A[i]]` is `C[0]` and it might equal `0` from analysis of previous loops. When you subtract `1` from it, you'll end up with `B[-1]` which breaks your code.